# Edit this code to remove two rows and two columns

Tags: matplotlib, math

I've got some code that produces a Cayley table for multiplication modulo 7, i.e. (Z/7Z, x).

I don't want it to print the first grey row or grey column.

I don't want it to display the second row and second column of zeros.

I don't want it to display the numbers, so colour = 'none' I guess.

I don't want it to display the dividing lines as black, but as 'none'.

I want to off-set the cmap, so 1 is now violet and 6 is red (not 0 --> 6, but 1 --> 6)

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create Cayley table
table = np.zeros((8, 8), dtype=int)
for i in range(8):
    for j in range(8):
        table[i][j] = ((i-1) * (j-1)) % 7

# Create figure and axis objects
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# Hide axes
ax.axis('off')

# Create table with rainbow colors
table_obj = ax.table(cellText=table.astype(str), loc='center', cellColours=plt.cm.get_cmap('rainbow')(table/6))


# Set table properties
table_obj.auto_set_font_size(False)
table_obj.set_fontsize(14)
table_obj.scale(1, 2)

# Color first row and first column
for i in range(8):
    cell = table_obj[0, i]
    cell.set_facecolor('grey')
    text = cell.get_text()
    if i == 0:
        text.set_text('')
    else:
        text.set_text(str(i-1))
    text.set_color('white')
    text.set_fontsize(14)
    text.set_position((0.5, 0.5))

for i in range(8):
    cell = table_obj[i, 0]
    cell.set_facecolor('grey')
    text = cell.get_text()
    if i == 0:
        text.set_text('')
    else:
        text.set_text(str(i-1))
    text.set_color('white')
    text.set_fontsize(14)
    text.set_position((0.5, 0.5))

# Add white '+' at position [0,0]
cell = table_obj[0, 0]
text = cell.get_text()
text.set_text('+')
text.set_color('white')
text.set_fontsize(14)
text.set_position((0.5, 0.5))

# Show plot
plt.show()
```

I tried changing the for loops, but those first two rows and columns still appear, and the entry table[0,0] just appears blank and is colour violet - which corresponds to 0.

```
# Create Cayley table
table = np.zeros((8, 8), dtype=int)
for i in range(1, 8):
    for j in range(1, 8):
        table[i][j] = ((i-1) * (j-1)) % 7

-- snip --

# Color first row and first column
for i in range(1, 8):
    cell = table_obj[0, i]
    cell.set_facecolor('grey')
    text = cell.get_text()
    if i == 0:
        text.set_text('')
    else:
        text.set_text(str(i-1))
    text.set_color('white')
    text.set_fontsize(14)
    text.set_position((0.5, 0.5))

for i in range(1, 8):
    cell = table_obj[i, 0]
    cell.set_facecolor('grey')
    text = cell.get_text()
    if i == 0:
        text.set_text('')
    else:
        text.set_text(str(i-1))
    text.set_color('white')
    text.set_fontsize(14)
    text.set_position((0.5, 0.5))

-- snip --
```

Comment: Hello! Your problem doesn't exactly look hard, but it's impossible to understand it without reading your whole code and taking time to understand every line of code. Could you maybe post an image of the table as it is now, and then explain what you would want to do differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to want to show a heatmap of a mod 7 multiplication table, without the zeros.  This can be created with a few lines of seaborn code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

num = 7
num_range = np.arange(1, num)
mult = num_range.reshape(1, -1) * num_range.reshape(-1, 1) % num

sns.heatmap(mult, xticklabels=False, yticklabels=False, annot=False, square=True,
            cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow', num), cbar=False)
plt.show()
```

[image: mod 7 multiplication table]

Via seaborn's options, you can tweak how it looks like. Here is an example. Just switch off the modifications you don't want.

```py
ax = sns.heatmap(mult, xticklabels=True, yticklabels=True, annot=True, square=True, linewidths=1,
                 cmap=plt.get_cmap('rainbow', num - 1), cbar=True, vmin=0.5, vmax=num - 0.5)
ax.tick_params(labeltop=True, labelbottom=False, length=0)
```

[image: tweaked multiplication table]

Comment: This is wonderful. thank you! This is a build-up to what I really want to do. I want to create the table for an elliptic curve. It doesn't matter about the maths, but I have a list of points [(x1, y1), ..., (xn, yn)] and a way of combining these points so I always get something on my list as an answer, So F((xi, yi), (xj, yj)) = (xk, yk). I want to male the "multiplication table" for this list. I was going to give each of my points a number: (x1, y1) --> 1, ..., (xn, yn) --> n. Then the multiplication table would be an n-by-n square with the numbers 1, ..., n inside, because f(i, j) = k.